# Compress/Alternative code:-

Tags: php, html, css

I spent half a day writing the content section of my index page of my website but when I tried adding another image to the list of images (There is currently 6) it was a very long and annoying process. (Website: http://rikahiyuka.com)

Is there a way to write the code so that it will be easier to add more buttons (The Images)?

Things that are linked per image listed:
- JQuery
- Div (Link)

The most annoying part is adding to the JQuery.

Is there a better way to write the code for the buttons/images in the content section so it is more compact and easier to edit?

Note: The only section of the index.php file that uses PHP is the footer for the year number.

Comment: Should we just randomly guess what your PHP and JS look like?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. The content section does not contain any PHP code. The only section that does contain PHP is the footer. My apologies.

Comment: Well, there's part of your problem right there.  :P  You could simply have an array of images and let PHP loop through them and generate the HTML.

Comment: So for that div containing the images, I could use a PHP include or something? I should also mention I have about no knowledge on how to use PHP. Even if it generates the html for the images through an array, how would it know how to generate the JQuery script and the Divs in the #IDTopic section?

Comment: Eh.  The jQuery.  The reason it's so complicated is because you're tying everything to specific elements.  You would do well to generalize it....use classes rather than IDs for a bunch of it, etc.  Ideally you want to make the jQuery code such that you never have to touch it again.

Comment: How would I use classes to generalise the jQuery? The way I understood it, is only change all the IDs to Classes which wouldn't make much difference in the jQuery... could you give some examples of how it would be done?

Comment: Give your clickables a class that indicates they're clickable, and a `data-` attribute that relates them to the stuff that should become visible...and give the paragraphs and such a class that indicates that's what they are.  At that point, you can tell the clickables "hey, when you're clicked, tell your respective paragraph to show, and all the others to hide".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Give your clickables a class that indicates they're clickable" and why it is necessary. Also I read about the data- attribute and it does look like it will work. However, I do not know where the data- attributes should be added and how to use it with the jQuery script.

Comment: If you don't even understand what i'm talking about, then you might want to find a developer.  This is all pretty basic, standard HTML/JS development stuff, and you're only going to learn so much via a Q/A forum.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help, I'll see what can I figure out. (^_^)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing each image individually, just write one function:

```
function showhide(shownum) {
  $("#Ip1, #Ip2, #Ip3, #Ip4, #Ip5, #Ip6").hide();
  $("#Il1, #Il2, #Il3, #Il4, #Il5, #Il6, #IDTopic").hide();
  $("#Ip" + shownum + ", #IDTopic, #Il" + shownum).show();
}
```

Then, if you want to show something, you simply call this function:

`showhide(6);`

You can put it in your HTML (like so:)

```
<td>
<img id="Iimg1" class="c-img" src="#" title="Show 1" onclick="showhide(1) />
</td>
```

or edit your JavaScript:

```
$("#Iimg1").click(function(){
showhide(1);
});
```

Replacing 1 with whichever link you want to show. This will make it much quicker and much less annoying because you won't have to list out each element to show and hide. Just call the `showhide` function :) It basically works by, instead of worrying about hiding everything except the one clicked on, hiding ALL of the links. Then, showing the one requested.

Comment: I understood the answer the second time I read it. This will surely help in future development. Thanks you very much, it is very appreciated. (^_^)